# Get the total Count and Sum of total Amount from down line record using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can we Count and Sum all down-line rows to their up-line using SQL.

Current data:

```
  ST_ID    UPLINE   AMOUNT
  ---------------------------
  44930   52001    400
  52016   52001    300
  52001   9024     432
  76985   9024     100
  12123   35119    234
  12642   35119    213
  12332   23141    654
```

Here in above table, `uplinedata` `52001` two `ST_ID` with amount `400` and `300` each with total sum of `700` and ST_ID has `52001` as well with Amount `400`, so total amount for `5201` will be `400 + 300 + 432 = 1132` and again upline `9024` has `ST_ID` of `52001` with `432 + 700` with total of `1132`.

Expected Output:

```
  UPLINE   AMOUNT  CNT
  ------------------------
  52001    1132    2       (400 +300 + 432 | 1+1+1)
  9024     1232    4       (700 + 432 + 100 | 2+1+1 = 4)
  35119    447     2       (234 + 213 | 1+1 = 2)
  23141    654     1
```

I thought of recursive CTE but could not able to gather the logic. Do anyone have any idea to achieve this. I am using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Your data is missing an implied ordering that you have not shown; you need to provide another column that orders `upline` as you expect.

Comment: Should edit the output table to reflect the narrative. 700 should be 1132.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understood, the Upline column is connected to ST_ID column, and you want to find the sum and count grouped by (Upline + all the matched values from ST_ID). i.e. Upline = 9024 is connected to ST_ID = 52001, so the sum for Upline = 9024 will be (432 + 100 from 9024 plus 300 + 400 from 52001).

You could use a recursive CTE as the following:

```
With CTE As
(
  Select ST_ID, Upline, Amount From table_name
  Union All
  Select T.ST_ID, T.Upline, C.Amount
  From table_name T Join CTE C
  On C.Upline = T.ST_ID
)
Select Upline, 
       Sum(Amount) As Amount, 
       Count(*) As Cnt
From CTE
Group By Upline
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/EXGPfJvG).

Update according to the new requirement (in addition to the sum of the the previous query add the sum of values where ST_ID=Upline):

```
With CTE As
(
  Select * From table_name
  Union All
  Select T.ST_ID, T.Upline, C.AMOUNT
  From table_name T Join CTE C
  On C.Upline = T.ST_ID
)
Select C.Upline, 
       Sum(C.Amount) + ISNULL(Sum(Distinct T.Amount), 0) As Amount, 
       Count(*) + Count(Distinct T.Amount) As Cnt
From CTE C Left Join table_name T
On C.Upline = T.ST_ID
Group By C.Upline
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WXI8ioUn).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was correct according to my last request for there was misunderstanding in requirements and now I updated the correct expected result. Could you please look into updated expected results ?

Comment: You are welcome, so you want in addition of the sum of this query the sum of values where ST_ID=Upline, Like this https://dbfiddle.uk/WXI8ioUn

Comment: Kindly, let me know if the query in the previous comment is OK so I  can update the answer.